# Ruby CSV << [] does not line break properly

Tags: ruby, excel, vba, csv

I have a wired issue here,

I use standard CSV << ["a", "b"] in my code, and the output file behaves just fine in Excel and Sublime Text 2(elegantly line break)

However I open the file with Windows notepad, it turns out to be a single line.

And I try to use VBA to read this file line by line, only to get one single line.

Here is my code，

```
require "csv"
CSV::open("some_file.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << ["a", "b"]
  csv << ["a1", "b1"]
end
```

In Sublime Text 2 I get

```
a,b
a1,b1
```

However in Windows notepad, I only get

```
a,ba1, b1
```

Any idea why?

[update]
It was Windows notepad, not Windows Text Editor, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: can you open it in `"wb"` mode ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, Thanks. Yes, I tried '"wb"' mode in ruby, it got me the same thing.

Comment: Ok.. That's not needed. Do something `CSV::open("some_file.csv", "w", :row_sep => '\r\n')` and let me know.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thank you very much. It works out! (It seems to be "\r\n")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that unix and windows systems do not handle newline representation the same way. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). To simplify, unix uses `LF`, which is written as `\n` whereas windows expects `CR+LF`: `\r\n`. This is why it appears to be on the same line when opening in windows. You can use @arup-rakshit solution, extra `\r` should not hurt, but you may need to specify it when reading it again. Otherwise, there are some various tools to convert a unix file to a windows file and vice versa.

Comment: Good! I thought I would put that as answer, but you did on-behalf of me, so I am glad. :-)